# Get All International Strings in Grails from the current locale?

Tags: grails, internationalization

Is there a method in the plugin for internationalization that will let me get all the strings + names defined for a particular locale or the current locale?

Comment: Interesting - why would you want to do that?

Comment: To send them to a client plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Internationalized strings are stored in properties files under grails-app/i18n You can read them using the ResourceBundle class.

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle('i18n.messages', locale)
```

and then iterate through the keys:

```
for(String key, bundle.getKeys()){
...
}
```

That should do the trick.

Vincent Giguère